# How to make a blacklist of endpoints in AspNetCoreRateLimit nuget package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, rate-limiting

I recently started using the [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit) nuget package, but I don't know and can't find how to make a blacklist for endpoints?

I tried doing this:

```
"IpRateLimiting": {
  "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
  "StackBlockedRequests": true,
  "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
  "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
  "HttpStatusCode": 429,
  "IpWhitelist": [],
  "EndpointWhitelist": [],
  "ClientWhitelist": [],
  "GeneralRules": [
    {
      // This Endpoint doesn't accept an array of endpoints, it only works
      // when you pass a single endpoint like this: "Endpoint": "post:/api/auth/*"
      // this makes it so cumbersome to add every endpoint in it's own block and
      // each with 3 rules
      "Endpoint": [
        "get:/api/user/SearchByEmailOrPhone/*",
        "post:/api/auth/*",
        "get:/api/user/SetNewsletterSubscription/*"
      ],
      "Period": "15s",
      "Limit": 3
    },
    {
      "Endpoint": [
        "get:/api/user/SearchByEmailOrPhone/*",
        "post:/api/auth/*",
        "get:/api/user/SetNewsletterSubscription/*"
      ],
      "Period": "1m",
      "Limit": 6
    },
    {
      "Endpoint": [
        "get:/api/user/SearchByEmailOrPhone/*",
        "post:/api/auth/*",
        "get:/api/user/SetNewsletterSubscription/*"
      ],
      "Period": "5m",
      "Limit": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

but apparently, the `Endpoint` under `GeneralRules`, doesn't accept an array of endpoints and it only works with a single endpoint in each `Endpoint`, but it'll be so cumbersome if I add all of my endpoints separately AND each of them with 3 limitation rules, so currently I have 3 endpoints that I want to add to the blacklist, 3 endpoints each with 3 rules will be 9 of these rule blocks (and it will probably get more than that), is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no better way to do this.The reason is below:

In program.cs we can configure the Rate Limit configuration like below too:

```
builder.Services.Configure<IpRateLimitOptions>(options =>
{
    options.EnableEndpointRateLimiting = true;
    options.StackBlockedRequests = false;
    options.HttpStatusCode = 429;
    options.ClientIdHeader = "Client-Id";
    options.GeneralRules = new List<RateLimitRule>
        {
            new RateLimitRule
            {
                Endpoint = "*",
                Period = "10s",
                Limit = 2
            }
        };
});
```

Use 12,  we can see  `Endpoint` is not a list in RateLimitRule class, so Endpoint doesn't accept an array of endpoints.

```
public class RateLimitRule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// HTTP verb and path 
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>
        /// get:/api/values
        /// *:/api/values
        /// *
        /// </example>
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any other packages for rate limiting the API? this package works fine, especially being able to add multiple rules, but not being able to create a blacklist of endpoints easily is not cool.